# Is it correct to do some SQLite queries in UI thread?

Tags: android

I have to load some data from local SQLite database, and I don't know if it's better to do it inside an Asynctask or don't worry if I do it in the UI thread..

Thanks!

Comment: If the data you are querying is small then I don't think UI thread is going to have any problem. But if the data is big then ideally you should use `AsyncTask` for better user experience.

Comment: If the data is big, you can use `AsyncTask` or `Loader`s.: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html

Comment: Also depends, whether the query is a precondition for the UI loading or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database queries can be a heavy duty especially if the table is large.. sometimes even if the table isn't that big, on some devices it can cause your application to lag..

so I recommend doing this in a separate thread preferably using a `Loader` to avoid handling all the stuff related to your activity's life cycle.

Comment: Yes, it is always a good practice to put data loading into background thread since you are unable to predict loading time due to device specific problems